# jquery add value depending on date

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2013

I have a query that returns items from a SharePoint Custom List. Depending on the date of the item I want to add a value to the results.

```
var urlForAllItems = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('OIE Alerts')/Items?"
    + "$select=Title,Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event,Country0/Title,Country0/Column2&$expand=Country0&"
    + "$filter=Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event gt '"+startDate+"'&$orderby=Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event desc";
```

If the item is from last month I want to add "NEW", if it is from the month before last month I want to add "OLD". The query only returns items from the last two months through 'startDate'.

```
Function getItems(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        async:false,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        },
        success: function (data) {
             var items = data.d.results;
             for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
                 countryCode = items[i].Country0.Column2;                          
    // need code here: countryData cane be "OLD" or "NEW"
                 dataset[countryCode] = countryData;
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nisse, I am fairly new here so still struggling with the layout.

Comment: `targetDate.setDate(today.getDate()-60);
    var someDate = new Date('2017-11-11');
    if (someDate > targetDate || someDate < startDate) {
        dataset[countryCode] = "OLD";
        alert("OLD");
        alert(targetDate + "   " + startDate);
    } else {
        dataset[countryCode] = "NEW";
        alert("NEW");
   }`

I am trying this code but somehow it always returns "OLD", even when someDate < startDate.

What's wrong in my code?